# How to use OpenCV 4.4.0 (with contrib modules) in Java on Windows?

Tags: java, opencv, shared-libraries

I've compiled OpenCV 4.4.0 from source on Windows 64 bit along with java bindings and I'm trying to compile a basic test, however I'm running into unexpected errors.

Here's how I've setup an eclipse project:

[image: Eclipse project displaying OpenCV java and native library files]

and this how the jar references the native libraries:

[image: Java project build properties of the OpenCV java library pointing to native DLLs]

And this is the basic test snippet:

```
import org.opencv.core.*;

public class CVTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.load(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
                
    }

}
```

which throws this exception:

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Expecting an absolute path of the library: opencv_java440
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:806)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
at CVTest.main(CVTest.java:8)
```

I've tried hardcoding the absolute path as a test:

```
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_java440.dll");
```

However I run into this exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

```
C:\Users\george.profenza\Documents\eclipse\CVTest\lib\opencv_java440.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1817)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at CVTest.main(CVTest.java:9)
```

I didn't expect this as I've compiled OpenCV 4 64-bit and I'm running this on JVM 1.8 64-bit.

I've tried manually loading one library at a time and using [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) and finally managed to instantiate a `Mat` like so:

```
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_core440.dll");
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_imgproc440.dll");
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_imgcodecs440.dll");
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_img_hash440.dll");
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg440_64.dll");
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_videoio440.dll");      
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_photo440.dll");
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_xphoto440.dll");

System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_flann440.dll");
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_features2d440.dll");

System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_calib3d440.dll");
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_phase_unwrapping440.dll");
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_structured_light440.dll");

System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_xfeatures2d440.dll");
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_video440.dll");        
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_ximgproc440.dll");
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_aruco440.dll");
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_bgsegm440.dll");
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_bioinspired440.dll");

System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_objdetect440.dll");
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_face440.dll");

System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_dnn440.dll");
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_tracking440.dll");
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_plot440.dll");

System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_ml440.dll");
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_text440.dll");


// f.finally load the JNI wrapper native lib
System.load("C:\\Users\\george.profenza\\Documents\\eclipse\\CVTest\\lib\\opencv_java440.dll");
```

This works but hardcoding every single DLL in that order feels like a messy hack.
Has anyone else ran into this scenario ?

What is the elegant way of loading the OpenCV 4 library in Java on Windows ?

To facilitate testing I've uploaded the following:

- [opencv_440_windows32.zip](http://lifesine.eu/so/opencv_440_windows32.zip): 32 bit headers/dynamic libraries (as well as java wrapper)
- [opencv_440_windows64.zip](http://lifesine.eu/so/opencv_440_windows64.zip): 64 bit headers/dynamic libraries (as well as java wrapper)

**Update**

Here are the static libs, including java bindings based on José's excellent anwer:

- [opencv_440_static_windows32.zip](http://lifesine.eu/so/opencv_440_static_windows32.zip)
- [opencv_440_static_windows64.zip](http://lifesine.eu/so/opencv_440_static_windows64.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try to set the `java.library.path` property to indicate the JVM where to find native libraries (I suppose you need to configure `C:/Users/george.profenza/Documents/eclipse/CVTest/lib\` in your case).

From the command line (or Eclipse Run/Debug configurations), you can include the required libraries as follows:

```sh
java -Djava.library.path=<path_to_dlls> <main class>
```

In the Java code, you can set the property like this:

```java
System.setProperty(“java.library.path”, “/path/to/dlls”);
```

In addition to modifying the Run/Debug configurations to include the `-Djava.library.path` in Eclipse, to set the `java.library.path` property in this IDE you can follow several guides (look at [this](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/04/what-is-javalibrarypath-how-to-set-in-Eclipse.html), for instance). Basically:

1. Right click into your project in the `Package Explorer`.
2. Select the `Build Path → Configure Build Path...` option.
3. In the window that appears, select the `Libraries` tab.
4. Expand the `JRE System library` option, and select the `Native library location`.
5. Click on the `Edit...` button at the right panel.
6. Locate the required libraries and then click `OK`.

It could be necessary to build the library without shared libs to avoid problems with dll dependencies. You can see an in depth explanation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d52/tutorial_java_dev_intro.html). Note where the author says:

> When OpenCV is built as a set of static libraries (`-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` option) the Java bindings dynamic library is all-sufficient, i.e. doesn't depend on other OpenCV libs, but includes all the OpenCV code inside.

Comment: Thanks Jose: I've used that before with other libraries and it worked.
In this case it didn't. I've tried both setting the command line argument and doing the same at runtime via `System.setProperty` but no joy. If do comment loading the dependant dlls in the right order it does work, but that's what I'm trying to avoid. Would you be able to give it a quick test using the zip I posted above ?

Comment: Of course @GeorgeProfenza, I use Mac, but I will try to test it in my Windows virtual machine.

Comment: I understand it's a bit of pain: the effort is very much appreciated

Comment: I have been studying the problem and doing some tests. Indeed, it seems that in this case the libraries have some dependencies on each other that makes the loading process not working properly. In any case, it seems that including in ```java.library.path``` the JNI native library ```opencv_java440.dll```, and dynamically load it, is adequate (this is also done in the Maven dependency from ```org.openpnp```). Continues in the next comment

Comment: The only problem lies in solving the rest of the dlls. Is it possible that, when building them from source code, something has not been correctly referenced in the OS? Would it be possible to include the directory where these dlls reside in the ```PATH``` variable? I have not examined the cmake files in detail, and I suppose that it will not be possible, but could all the libraries be linked in a single dll so we can reference it in the code as a single dependency?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Please, take into consideration: it you need to try any of the things indicated in the comments above, and use ```java.library.path```, you must use ```System.loadLibrary``` and not ```System.load```.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I think that the best way to solve the problem is link all the libraries in one dll (if you can also include contributions) that you can load, as we said in the morning. It seems that, at least some time ago, it was possible. I updated the answer with the relevant information.

Comment: I've tried using `java.library.path` in conjuction with `System.loadLibrary` however that didn't work. Adding the folder containing the other DLLs to the `PATH` environment variable does the trick, however I'd need to somehow do that programmatically. I've tried `setx` via `Runtime.exec` however that works on the second run (when the variable becomes available). Calling `set` via `Runtime` didn't work. I'll try building the static version of the library and will get back to you with results.  Many thanks

Comment: I am very happy to hear that the comments have been helpful. Please let me know if I can help you in any way.

Comment: I believe `java.library.path` simply sets the native path so the .jar library can access the .dll it needs, however if that dll loads other dll files this path won't suffice (`opencv_java440.dll: Can't find dependent libraries`) while `%PATH%` will (though it's not easy to set at runtime in one go (and risks breaking local %PATH% entries is incorrectly used)). I remember reading the static libraries part in the OpenCV docs, but never knew why. I'm sort of learning that the hard way: compiling OpenCV as a static library made OpenCV java for Windows work as expected ! Woo hoo! Thanks José !

Comment: Great! I am very happy to know that everything is finally working as expected! Thanks George!

Answer (score 2):

Try pre-compiled libs should be easier.

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openpnp/opencv -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0-2</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried this lib a few year ago, it works.

Comment: That's not a bad idea (+1), however, I need to use version `4.4.0-pre` with `contrib` modules (if it's precompiled, great, but ideally that an official build)